# Getting the security groups allowing a specific port

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-security-group

Let's say I want to get the list of security groups that allows 443 port in the outbound rules. I am using this documentation (https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2/client/describe_security_group_rules.html) was able to go to the far where I can use filter egress.ip-permission.from-port to get a list of groups with outbound rules specify 443 as starting port to allow. But the list doesn't contain any security groups that says to allow 440-449 port ranges.

Is there a way I could say egress.ip-permission.from-port >= 443 and egress.ip-permission.to-port <=443 to get exactly what I wanted?

Below is the sample code, I am using python boto3 lib:

```
import boto3


def _describe_security_groups(client, Filter):
    response = client.describe_security_groups(Filters=Filter, DryRun=False, MaxResults=1000)

    for security_group in response["SecurityGroups"]:
        print("Name: " + security_group["GroupName"] +
              " Id: " + security_group["GroupId"])


client = boto3.client("ec2")
port = '443'
Filter_outbound_port = [
    {"Name": "egress.ip-permission.from-port", "Values": [port]},
]

print("++++Outbound security groups++++")
_describe_security_groups(client, Filter_outbound_port)
```

Comment: You will need to loop through each rule and use Python to check the value of the port range, instead of using a filter.

Comment: Yes, Doing the same. Native boto3 library don't have any filters.

Comment: It's a limitation of the AWS API, not just boto3.